# folium, plugins.TimestampedGeoJson, "Time not avaliable"

Tags: python, folium

I want to draw Timestamped GeoJSON using plugins.TimestampedGeoJson.

But my time bar in folium map shows "Time not available" and doesn't work.

I cannot find which part of my variables are wrong.

Variables I used are as follows.

How can I make my time bar work?

```
points




[{'coordinates': [[37.4725028, 126.4313798],
   [37.478525899999994, 126.6663152],
   [37.561648999999996, 126.79433700000001]],
  'popup': 1,
  'time': '2020-01-19'},
 {'coordinates': [[37.679657, 126.763737],
   [37.4725028, 126.4313798],
   [37.0796065, 127.0561043],
   [37.0220402, 126.8134938],
   [37.557176, 127.00768799999999]],
  'popup': 1,
  'time': '2020-01-20'},
 {'coordinates': [[37.673517, 126.7553],
   [37.670964, 126.761146],
   [37.679657, 126.763737],
   [37.520878, 127.02286299999999],
   [37.524661, 127.028002],
   [37.503137, 127.04909099999999],
   [37.0520115, 126.91724440000002],
   [37.463504, 126.65055600000001]],
  'popup': 1,
  'time': '2020-01-21'},
 {'coordinates': [[37.560362700000006, 126.776299],
   [37.567226899999994, 126.75337079999998],
   [37.549605299999996, 126.86608829999999],
   [37.567226899999994, 126.75337079999998],
   [37.5672454, 127.00347020000001],
   [37.524661, 127.028002],
   [37.530772, 127.031924],
   [37.503137, 127.04909099999999],
   [37.0220402, 126.8134938],
   [37.523118200000006, 127.03281489999999],
   [37.555136, 126.97048899999999]],
  'popup': 1,
  'time': '2020-01-22'},
 {'coordinates': [[37.524703, 127.015943],
   [37.500735, 127.036373],
   [37.494607, 127.06329199999999],
   [37.503137, 127.04909099999999],
   [37.0220402, 126.8134938],
   [37.483702, 126.77811299999999]],
  'popup': 1,
  'time': '2020-01-23'},
 {'coordinates': [[37.524661, 127.028002],
   [37.658513, 126.832025],
   [37.674671999999994, 126.776701],
   [37.678166, 126.812165],
   [37.0220402, 126.8134938],
   [37.5616902, 126.97456809999998],
   [37.266184, 126.999655],
   [37.263417, 127.028654],
   [37.361576, 126.935174]],
  'popup': 1,
  'time': '2020-01-24'},
 {'coordinates': [[37.679657, 126.763737],
   [37.642371999999995, 126.831253],
   [37.0520115, 126.91724440000002],
   [37.5616902, 126.97456809999998],
   [37.483538, 127.032643],
   [35.967625, 126.73678899999999],
   [35.967625, 126.73678899999999],
   [37.359123, 126.93095500000001],
   [37.359123, 126.93095500000001]],
  'popup': 1,
  'time': '2020-01-25'},
 {'coordinates': [[37.35132410000001, 127.12124329999999],
   [37.5917891, 127.0164831],
   [37.564001, 127.02953500000001],
   [37.5903342, 127.01303200000001],
   [37.590492100000006, 127.0119803],
   [37.590611700000004, 126.9441293],
   [37.5863425, 126.99763390000001],
   [37.5616902, 126.97456809999998],
   [35.9867, 126.70813000000001]],
  'popup': 1,
  'time': '2020-01-26'},
 {'coordinates': [[37.5920615, 127.01670959999998],
   [37.590611700000004, 126.9441293],
   [37.5921286, 126.98387890000001],
   [37.5863425, 126.99763390000001],
   [37.5863425, 126.99763390000001],
   [37.5863425, 126.99763390000001],
   [37.5616902, 126.97456809999998],
   [35.968089, 126.716128],
   [37.557176, 127.00768799999999]],
  'popup': 1,
  'time': '2020-01-27'},
 {'coordinates': [[37.5916736, 127.016226],
   [37.5854777, 127.08637140000002],
   [37.5982157, 127.0797739],
   [37.5236782, 127.04434930000001],
   [37.60656420000001, 127.09043],
   [37.5616902, 126.97456809999998],
   [35.954685, 126.71244399999999],
   [37.483702, 126.77811299999999]],
  'popup': 1,
  'time': '2020-01-28'},
 {'coordinates': [[37.594741799999994, 127.0728561],
   [37.60656420000001, 127.09043],
   [37.5616902, 126.97456809999998],
   [35.976046000000004, 126.705522],
   [35.982751, 126.734844]],
  'popup': 1,
  'time': '2020-01-29'},
 {'coordinates': [[37.5647424, 126.99496140000001],
   [37.579669, 126.99897],
   [35.964349, 126.959676],
   [37.641158000000004, 126.791979],
   [37.5863425, 126.99763390000001],
   [37.641158000000004, 126.791979],
   [37.5863425, 126.99763390000001],
   [37.498415, 126.762864]],
  'popup': 1,
  'time': '2020-01-30'},
 {'coordinates': [[35.964349, 126.959676],
   [37.5673125, 126.9706395],
   [37.579669, 126.99897],
   [37.579669, 126.99897],
   [37.561648, 126.7855822],
   [37.481458, 126.7804963]],
  'popup': 1,
  'time': '2020-01-31'},
 {'coordinates': [[37.351375, 127.123411],
   [37.481458, 126.7804963],
   [37.304349, 127.0079881],
   [37.391714799999995, 127.147098]],
  'popup': 1,
  'time': '2020-02-01'},
 {'coordinates': [[37.5672412, 127.00347020000001], [37.351375, 127.123411]],
  'popup': 1,
  'time': '2020-02-02'}]
```

Below is my features variable.

```
features

[{'geometry': {'coordinates': [[37.4725028, 126.4313798],
    [37.478525899999994, 126.6663152],
    [37.561648999999996, 126.79433700000001]],
   'type': 'Point'},
  'properties': {'icon': 'marker',
   'iconstyle': {'iconSize': [20, 20],
    'iconUrl': 'http://downloadicons.net/sites/default/files/small-house-with-a-chimney-icon-70053.png'},
   'id': 'house',
   'popup': 1,
   'time': '2020-01-19'},
  'type': 'Feature'},
 {'geometry': {'coordinates': [[37.679657, 126.763737],
    [37.4725028, 126.4313798],
    [37.0796065, 127.0561043],
    [37.0220402, 126.8134938],
    [37.557176, 127.00768799999999]],
   'type': 'Point'},
  'properties': {'icon': 'marker',
   'iconstyle': {'iconSize': [20, 20],
    'iconUrl': 'http://downloadicons.net/sites/default/files/small-house-with-a-chimney-icon-70053.png'},
   'id': 'house',
   'popup': 1,
   'time': '2020-01-20'},
  'type': 'Feature'},
 {'geometry': {'coordinates': [[37.673517, 126.7553],
    [37.670964, 126.761146],
    [37.679657, 126.763737],
    [37.520878, 127.02286299999999],
    [37.524661, 127.028002],
    [37.503137, 127.04909099999999],
    [37.0520115, 126.91724440000002],
    [37.463504, 126.65055600000001]],
   'type': 'Point'},
  'properties': {'icon': 'marker',
   'iconstyle': {'iconSize': [20, 20],
    'iconUrl': 'http://downloadicons.net/sites/default/files/small-house-with-a-chimney-icon-70053.png'},
   'id': 'house',
   'popup': 1,
   'time': '2020-01-21'},
  'type': 'Feature'},
 {'geometry': {'coordinates': [[37.560362700000006, 126.776299],
    [37.567226899999994, 126.75337079999998],
    [37.549605299999996, 126.86608829999999],
    [37.567226899999994, 126.75337079999998],
    [37.5672454, 127.00347020000001],
    [37.524661, 127.028002],
    [37.530772, 127.031924],
    [37.503137, 127.04909099999999],
    [37.0220402, 126.8134938],
    [37.523118200000006, 127.03281489999999],
    [37.555136, 126.97048899999999]],
   'type': 'Point'},
  'properties': {'icon': 'marker',
   'iconstyle': {'iconSize': [20, 20],
    'iconUrl': 'http://downloadicons.net/sites/default/files/small-house-with-a-chimney-icon-70053.png'},
   'id': 'house',
   'popup': 1,
   'time': '2020-01-22'},
  'type': 'Feature'},
 {'geometry': {'coordinates': [[37.524703, 127.015943],
    [37.500735, 127.036373],
    [37.494607, 127.06329199999999],
    [37.503137, 127.04909099999999],
    [37.0220402, 126.8134938],
    [37.483702, 126.77811299999999]],
   'type': 'Point'},
  'properties': {'icon': 'marker',
   'iconstyle': {'iconSize': [20, 20],
    'iconUrl': 'http://downloadicons.net/sites/default/files/small-house-with-a-chimney-icon-70053.png'},
   'id': 'house',
   'popup': 1,
   'time': '2020-01-23'},
  'type': 'Feature'},
 {'geometry': {'coordinates': [[37.524661, 127.028002],
    [37.658513, 126.832025],
    [37.674671999999994, 126.776701],
    [37.678166, 126.812165],
    [37.0220402, 126.8134938],
    [37.5616902, 126.97456809999998],
    [37.266184, 126.999655],
    [37.263417, 127.028654],
    [37.361576, 126.935174]],
   'type': 'Point'},
  'properties': {'icon': 'marker',
   'iconstyle': {'iconSize': [20, 20],
    'iconUrl': 'http://downloadicons.net/sites/default/files/small-house-with-a-chimney-icon-70053.png'},
   'id': 'house',
   'popup': 1,
   'time': '2020-01-24'},
  'type': 'Feature'},
 {'geometry': {'coordinates': [[37.679657, 126.763737],
    [37.642371999999995, 126.831253],
    [37.0520115, 126.91724440000002],
    [37.5616902, 126.97456809999998],
    [37.483538, 127.032643],
    [35.967625, 126.73678899999999],
    [35.967625, 126.73678899999999],
    [37.359123, 126.93095500000001],
    [37.359123, 126.93095500000001]],
   'type': 'Point'},
  'properties': {'icon': 'marker',
   'iconstyle': {'iconSize': [20, 20],
    'iconUrl': 'http://downloadicons.net/sites/default/files/small-house-with-a-chimney-icon-70053.png'},
   'id': 'house',
   'popup': 1,
   'time': '2020-01-25'},
  'type': 'Feature'},
 {'geometry': {'coordinates': [[37.35132410000001, 127.12124329999999],
    [37.5917891, 127.0164831],
    [37.564001, 127.02953500000001],
    [37.5903342, 127.01303200000001],
    [37.590492100000006, 127.0119803],
    [37.590611700000004, 126.9441293],
    [37.5863425, 126.99763390000001],
    [37.5616902, 126.97456809999998],
    [35.9867, 126.70813000000001]],
   'type': 'Point'},
  'properties': {'icon': 'marker',
   'iconstyle': {'iconSize': [20, 20],
    'iconUrl': 'http://downloadicons.net/sites/default/files/small-house-with-a-chimney-icon-70053.png'},
   'id': 'house',
   'popup': 1,
   'time': '2020-01-26'},
  'type': 'Feature'},
 {'geometry': {'coordinates': [[37.5920615, 127.01670959999998],
    [37.590611700000004, 126.9441293],
    [37.5921286, 126.98387890000001],
    [37.5863425, 126.99763390000001],
    [37.5863425, 126.99763390000001],
    [37.5863425, 126.99763390000001],
    [37.5616902, 126.97456809999998],
    [35.968089, 126.716128],
    [37.557176, 127.00768799999999]],
   'type': 'Point'},
  'properties': {'icon': 'marker',
   'iconstyle': {'iconSize': [20, 20],
    'iconUrl': 'http://downloadicons.net/sites/default/files/small-house-with-a-chimney-icon-70053.png'},
   'id': 'house',
   'popup': 1,
   'time': '2020-01-27'},
  'type': 'Feature'},
 {'geometry': {'coordinates': [[37.5916736, 127.016226],
    [37.5854777, 127.08637140000002],
    [37.5982157, 127.0797739],
    [37.5236782, 127.04434930000001],
    [37.60656420000001, 127.09043],
    [37.5616902, 126.97456809999998],
    [35.954685, 126.71244399999999],
    [37.483702, 126.77811299999999]],
   'type': 'Point'},
  'properties': {'icon': 'marker',
   'iconstyle': {'iconSize': [20, 20],
    'iconUrl': 'http://downloadicons.net/sites/default/files/small-house-with-a-chimney-icon-70053.png'},
   'id': 'house',
   'popup': 1,
   'time': '2020-01-28'},
  'type': 'Feature'},
 {'geometry': {'coordinates': [[37.594741799999994, 127.0728561],
    [37.60656420000001, 127.09043],
    [37.5616902, 126.97456809999998],
    [35.976046000000004, 126.705522],
    [35.982751, 126.734844]],
   'type': 'Point'},
  'properties': {'icon': 'marker',
   'iconstyle': {'iconSize': [20, 20],
    'iconUrl': 'http://downloadicons.net/sites/default/files/small-house-with-a-chimney-icon-70053.png'},
   'id': 'house',
   'popup': 1,
   'time': '2020-01-29'},
  'type': 'Feature'},
 {'geometry': {'coordinates': [[37.5647424, 126.99496140000001],
    [37.579669, 126.99897],
    [35.964349, 126.959676],
    [37.641158000000004, 126.791979],
    [37.5863425, 126.99763390000001],
    [37.641158000000004, 126.791979],
    [37.5863425, 126.99763390000001],
    [37.498415, 126.762864]],
   'type': 'Point'},
  'properties': {'icon': 'marker',
   'iconstyle': {'iconSize': [20, 20],
    'iconUrl': 'http://downloadicons.net/sites/default/files/small-house-with-a-chimney-icon-70053.png'},
   'id': 'house',
   'popup': 1,
   'time': '2020-01-30'},
  'type': 'Feature'},
 {'geometry': {'coordinates': [[35.964349, 126.959676],
    [37.5673125, 126.9706395],
    [37.579669, 126.99897],
    [37.579669, 126.99897],
    [37.561648, 126.7855822],
    [37.481458, 126.7804963]],
   'type': 'Point'},
  'properties': {'icon': 'marker',
   'iconstyle': {'iconSize': [20, 20],
    'iconUrl': 'http://downloadicons.net/sites/default/files/small-house-with-a-chimney-icon-70053.png'},
   'id': 'house',
   'popup': 1,
   'time': '2020-01-31'},
  'type': 'Feature'},
 {'geometry': {'coordinates': [[37.351375, 127.123411],
    [37.481458, 126.7804963],
    [37.304349, 127.0079881],
    [37.391714799999995, 127.147098]],
   'type': 'Point'},
  'properties': {'icon': 'marker',
   'iconstyle': {'iconSize': [20, 20],
    'iconUrl': 'http://downloadicons.net/sites/default/files/small-house-with-a-chimney-icon-70053.png'},
   'id': 'house',
   'popup': 1,
   'time': '2020-02-01'},
  'type': 'Feature'},
 {'geometry': {'coordinates': [[37.5672412, 127.00347020000001],
    [37.351375, 127.123411]],
   'type': 'Point'},
  'properties': {'icon': 'marker',
   'iconstyle': {'iconSize': [20, 20],
    'iconUrl': 'http://downloadicons.net/sites/default/files/small-house-with-a-chimney-icon-70053.png'},
   'id': 'house',
   'popup': 1,
   'time': '2020-02-02'},
  'type': 'Feature'}]
```

I tried to draw folium map.

But my time lower left in map left doesn't work.

```
m = folium.Map([37.5650172,126.8494648], zoom_start = 10)


plugins.TimestampedGeoJson( { 'type': 'FeatureCollection', 'features': features },
                           period='P1D',
                           add_last_point=True,
                           auto_play=False,
                           loop=False,
                           max_speed=1,
                           loop_button=True,
                           date_options='YYYY-MM-DD',
                           time_slider_drag_update=True,
                           duration='P1D' ).add_to(m)

m
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please consider editing your question to simplify the examples, and also creating a small script that would reproduce the error you are facing. It is also nice if you can show the exact error message, since anyone facing a similar issue in the future may land here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, which was **solved by the following** in my case:

The issue you described occurs likely because your sub-dict-keyword `"time"` doesn't contain a list of equal length to the employed `"coordinates"` in each `"feature"`.

Also, I suggest you to rename `"time"` to `"times"`, as you will see in the original post on `GitHub` mentioned below.

**Hereafter, I made a minimal example based on your provided feature list:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# * Example of correct feature list with length 1 * #

## Coordinates
coordinate_list1 = [[37.4725028, 126.4313798],
    [37.478525899999994, 126.6663152],
    [37.561648999999996, 126.79433700000001]]
## Times
# NOTE: if the same timestamp applies to all coordinates, create list with repeating timestamp of same length as coordinate list
times_list1 = ['2020-01-19'] * len(coordinate_list1)

## Features
# NOTE: fill in the coordinates and times, and name the associated time-keyword "times"
features = [{
    'geometry': {
        'coordinates': coordinate_list1,
        'type': 'Point'
    },
    'properties': {
        'icon': 'marker',
        'iconstyle': {
            'iconSize': [20, 20],
            'iconUrl':
            'http://downloadicons.net/sites/default/files/small-house-with-a-chimney-icon-70053.png'
        },
        'id': 'house',
        'popup': 1,
        'times': times_list1
    },
    'type': 'Feature'
}]
```

*Fix this and it should work just fine.*

The solution was cited from [this discussion](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/issues/1235#issuecomment-562229472):

> [...] the plugin requires each `feature` to have a property `"times"`, which
>   should be a list containing either unix epoch timestamps in ms or ISO
>   format timestamps. See
>   https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/plugins.html#folium.plugins.TimestampedGeoJson

Comment: Note future me, it can also occur if the same time is repeated. ie. `len(set(times)) == len(set(coordinates))`

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.read_excel("file.xlsx")
IconUrl = "https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/1465/PNG/128/604bullettrain_100995.png"

m = folium.Map([37.5650172,126.8494648], zoom_start = 10)



# step 1
TempFeature = []
# do the following command for each marker 
temp_df = df.query(f"Marker_id == {1}")

TempFeature.append({ 'type': 'Feature',

                 'geometry': { 'type': 'LineString',

#                               example coordinates 
#                               [
#                                (-3.049648, 53.4372116),
#                                (-3.04967139134615, 53.4372056616587),
#                                (-3.04972986971154, 53.4371908158053),
#                                 .
#                                 .
#                                 .
#                                (-3.04972986971154, 53.4371908158053),
#                               ] 
                              'coordinates': list(zip(temp_df['Longitude'],temp_df['Latitude']))
                             },




                     'properties':{ 
                                     'icon': 'marker',
                                    'iconstyle': {'iconUrl': IconUrl, 'iconSize': [20, 20], },

                                     # time must be like the following format : '2018-12-01T05:53:00'
                                     'times': temp_df['Timetable'] ,
                                     'popup': '<html> <head></head>  <body> comments </body> </html>'
                      }})



# step 2
TimestampedGeoJson({
                        'type': 'FeatureCollection',
                        'features': TempFeature,
                        }
                        , period='P1D' 
                      ).add_to(m)

m
```

Comment: Posting code without any explanation / commentary isn't super helpful. I see that there are some comments in your code but it's helpful to add some text at the top explaining what the issue was and how you fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. For me it occured because my "times" value was too close to UTC 0. I literally wasted an hour before adding a couple of days to each timestamp.

I guess it was timezone shenanigans. (I knew this exact problem from nodered dashboard. -> Server and Client time mismatch)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35589682)

Comment: Ok, I'll never answer on SO again.