# TimestampedGeoJson with MultiPolygon shows Time Not Available

Tags: python, openstreetmap, geojson, geopandas, folium

I want to display a shape over the Canada map.
The idea is 2 shapes in different years.
But my slide at the end says:

"Time Not Available"

[image]

I tried to find here at the community, but I haven't found a problem like it.

Here you can find my [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WuelaQFq_CA1CCS5LAa4YcTVBi4qakub/view?usp=sharing) and here you can find my code:

```
import folium
from folium.plugins import TimestampedGeoJson
import json
import pandas as pd


with open('outputfile.json') as f:
    poly = json.load(f)


features = [
    {
        'type': 'Feature',
        'geometry': {
            'type': 'MultiPolygon',
            'coordinates': pol['coordinates'],
        },
        'properties': {
            'ABBREVNAME': pol['ABBREVNAME'],
            'time': pol['date'],
            }
    } for pol in poly
]

mapa = folium.Map(
    location = [56.130,-106.35],
    tiles='openstreetmap',
    zoom_start = 3
)

TimestampedGeoJson({'type': 'FeatureCollection', 'features': features}).add_to(mapa)
mapa
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem of yours of time not available and solved by following the example on the [documentation](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/plugins.html) and this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60044777/folium-plugins-timestampedgeojson-time-not-avaliable).

Basically, some key points from doc:

1- It's is not 'time' but "times" and it must be the same length of the list of coordinates

2- Lookout for time format it only takes ISO or ms epoch

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klESt.png)

Here is a code example of a store location code i was working, I didn't try Polygon yet but hope it helps u:

```
m = folium.Map([-23.579782, -46.687754], zoom_start=6, tiles="cartodbpositron")

TimestampedGeoJson({
    'type': 'FeatureCollection',
    'features': [
        {
            'type': 'Feature',
            'geometry': {
                'type': 'LineString',
                'coordinates': [[-46.687754, -23.579782]],
            },
            'properties': {
                'icon': 'marker',
                'iconstyle': {
                    'iconSize': [20, 20],
                    'iconUrl':
                        'https://img.icons8.com/ios-filled/50/000000/online-store.png'
                },
                'id': 'house',
                'popup': 1,
                'times': [1633046400000.0]
            }
        }, {
            'type': 'Feature',
            'geometry': {
                'type': 'LineString',
                'coordinates': [[-46.887754, -23.579782]],
            },
            'properties': {
                'icon': 'marker',
                'iconstyle': {
                    'iconSize': [20, 20],
                    'iconUrl':
                        'https://img.icons8.com/ios-filled/50/000000/online-store.png'
                },
                'id': 'house',
                'popup': 1,
                'times': [1635046400000.0]
            }
        }
    ]
}).add_to(m)

folium_static(m)
m.save('test.html')
```